# Disable session for WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to disable session for WCF service, by changing service contract

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://company.com/Services/", SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface IService
{ }

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service: IService
{ }
```

But then I step into the Operation with debugger, I can see that HttpContext.Current.Session is valid object.

What am I missing to dissable session state for WCF operation?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but to disable ASP.Net session RequirementsMode should be AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.NotAllowed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Instance context mode. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

You have 3 alternatives:

- Singleton, only one instance of the service shared by all calls
- Per Session, same session untill the client proxy is closed
- Per Call, disposed as soon as the call returns

It sounds that what you are after is per call. You may be able to see the session object in the debugger, but it will be disposed as soon as the call returns.